# Combining PEM file into a P12 file

Tags: openssl, private-key, pem, p12

Sorry for the lack of knowledge but i would like to know how to combine and merge two PEM files into one p12 file.
In general i would like to know the process of how to generate a p12 file containing a multi certifcates with their keys.

PS: i've used openssl to generate the keys and the certificate, also i've tried Keytoolstor explorer

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: concatenate both PEM files into a single PEM file, then use OpenSSL's pkcs12 function to convert the combined PEM into a PKCS#12 file.
For example:

```
cat cert1.pem cert2.pem >> both.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -in both.pem -out both.pfx
```

If you're on Windows, try either of these commands for concatenating both PEM files:

```
copy cert1.pem+cert2.pem both.pem
```

-or-

```
type cert1.pem > both.pem
type cert2.pem >> both.pem
```